# Unable to Install Rattle on Windows 10 despite multiple attempts

Tags: rattle

I am unable to install Rattle on my windows 10 pc. I installed in this order:

1. R,
2. R Studio,
3. RGTK2,
4. RGTK2 extras, and
5. rattle

When I tried to invoke rattle in the console this is what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Installation looks just fine.

After installing a package you need to load the package into the R session:

```
> library(rattle)
> rattle()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following video that helped me to successfully install Rattle on Windows 10:
[How to Install Rattle on Windows Easily and Quickly 2020](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aVD5g6wvf4)